# If the gradient of $f$ at $x$ has the same direction with $x$ for all $x$, is $f$ radial?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I would like to ask the following question: If $f:%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{n}\rightarrow%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
$ is a smooth function such that for all $x\in%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{n}$, its gradient at $x$ has the same direction with $x$, is the function
$f$ radial?

That is if there exists a function $g:%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{n}\rightarrow%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
$ such that $\nabla f\left(  x\right)  =g\left(  x\right)  x$, then is
$f\left(  x\right)  =f\left(  y\right)  $ when $\left\vert x\right\vert
=\left\vert y\right\vert ?$

Of course the radial functions have the above property. So I guess that the answer is yes. But so far I could not find proofs/ counterexamples for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you perform a path integral
$$
\int_\gamma \nabla f(\gamma(t)) \cdot \gamma'(t) dt =
\int_\gamma g(\gamma(t)) \gamma(t)  \cdot \gamma'(t) dt
$$
where $\gamma: [0, 1] \mapsto \mathbb R^n$ is a great arc of some sphere whose center is the origin. Then $\gamma'(t) $ is perpendicular to $\gamma(t)$ for all $t$  (simply differentiate $\gamma(t) \cdot \gamma(t) = const$), and hence the path integral is zero. But that same path integral represents $f(\gamma(1)) - f(\gamma(0))$. That shows that $f$ is constant on spheres about the origin, which is equivalent to your definition of "radial".